# How to write relative paths within a properties file

Tags: maven, properties-file

I've looked all over the site but nothing answers this.
I would like to know how to write a relative path WITHIN a .properties file.
This is for a project using Maven and the STS IDE.

My .properties file itself is being found and read just fine.  But, I am trying to create a relative path within the file itself and it's not working.

In the .properties file I have this entry:

```
XML_PROPERTIES=C:/projects/myProject/project-server/project-webapp/src/main/config/gs/myXmlFile.xml
```

I want to use a relative path here.  I've tried:

```
XML_PROPERTIES=../myXmlFile.xml
```

and

```
XML_PROPERTIES=../src/main/config/gs/myXmlFile.xml
```

and neither of those work.

I've also tried to use expression language to get the project directory like this:

```
XML_PROPERTIES=${basedir}/src/main/config/gs/myXmlFile.xml
```

The only things that works is the complete path.  Without it, I get errors that look similar to this:

```
Java Global Settings: XML properties file [../src/main/config/gs/agl_gs_NT.xml] not found.
```

Please let me know if I can provide any more details and I appreciate any responses.

Comment: I am afraid something's missing. Relative path to what? Properties are just strings. What are you trying to resolve the relative path against? The process's working directory? If you could post some code, it would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, Daniel.  It would be relative to where the project is stored on the computer.  You can see that the path that works starts with "C:/projects" and I would somehow like to have the path in the properties file be relative to the web app project that is loaded into STS via checking it out as a Maven project from Subversion.

As stated above, the complete path works just fine but I want a path relative to the project to work so that users don't need to manually change the path to match where they decide to store their projects.

Comment: And you don't want to use the Classloader to load the XML file for you? Most frameworks (Spring in particular) are able to load files without resorting to loading files directly from the filesystem. Is `src/main/config` declared as a resource directory in your POM?

Comment: For reasons that I can't get into here I have to load this file via a .properties file.  It's the way that my org. builds maven projects automatically for developers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the the maven resources plugin to [filter](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) your property value. Maven has several built in [properties](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/Maven+Properties+Guide) that should allow you to insert the correct path.